# MySQL to PostgreSQL converter

Tags: mysql, postgresql, schema, converters

Is there a good MySQL to PostgreSQL schema converter? (including Primary Keys, Foreign Keys, nulls, auto increment, different field types etc.).

I tried few but was not 100% successful (e.g. script for schema created from MySql could not work 100% in PG, from simple backticks that PG does not support to 'KEY's and other part of output that is not supported by PG).

Thanks!

Comment: Which ones did you try?

Comment: This one is written by a friend of mine and it's good: https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PGLOADER](http://pgloader.io/).
It claims to "Migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL. In one command.".
I have used it with great success.

Here are some [details](http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html).
There's also a video about the software.
On Ubuntu, the software is part of the standard packages.
(apt install pgloader).

Comment: Can this run on CentOS (EC2)? Thanks.

Comment: I will mark answer as accepted but trough my testing - noticed that is not 100% good (maybe 98% is ok). I had to manually fix few things around foreign keys and similar but overall is better than some other solutions.. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, i had to adapt a few things, too, at the time. If you have 10 tables only, you could translate them by hand. If you have 250 tables, then you might want to use PGLOADER :)